# Separar e imprimir itens do Objeto no HTML

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, json

Tenho esse script:

```
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

        var txt = this.responseText;
        var obj = JSON.parse(txt);
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = obj.value + ", " + obj.uri + " ... <br>";
    }
  };

  xhttp.open("GET", "link?order=desc&cli=9999999999", true);
 
  xhttp.send();
```

que me retorna o conteúdo abaixo.

```
{
  "items": [{
    "Value": 2149.44,
    "boleto": {
      "uri": "link.pdf",
      "digits": "0000000000000000000000000000000000000",
      "bank": "Boston Bank"
    },
    "doc": "999999-RNF",
    "dueDate": "2018-10-11",
    "cnpjCLI": "999999999999",
    "cnpjREP": "999999999999"
  }, {
    "Value": 2149.44,
    "boleto": {
      "uri": "link.pdf",
      "digits": "0000000000000000000000000000000000000",
      "bank": "Boston Bank"
    },
    "doc": "999999-RNF",
    "dueDate": "2018-10-11",
    "cnpjCLI": "999999999999",
    "cnpjREP": "999999999999"
  } {
    "Value": 2149.44,
    "boleto": {
      "uri": "link.pdf",
      "digits": "0000000000000000000000000000000000000",
      "bank": "Boston Bank"
    },
    "doc": "999999-RNF",
    "dueDate": "2018-10-11",
    "cnpjCLI": "999999999999",
    "cnpjREP": "999999999999"
  } {
    "Value": 2149.44,
    "boleto": {
      "uri": "link.pdf",
      "digits": "0000000000000000000000000000000000000",
      "bank": "Boston Bank"
    },
    "doc": "999999-RNF",
    "dueDate": "2018-10-11",
    "cnpjCLI": "999999999999",
    "cnpjREP": "999999999999"
  } {
    "Value": 2149.44,
    "boleto": {
      "uri": "link.pdf",
      "digits": "0000000000000000000000000000000000000",
      "bank": "Boston Bank"
    },
    "doc": "999999-RNF",
    "dueDate": "2018-10-11",
    "cnpjCLI": "999999999999",
    "cnpjREP": "999999999999"
  } {
    "Value": 2149.44,
    "boleto": {
      "uri": "link.pdf",
      "digits": "0000000000000000000000000000000000000",
      "bank": "Boston Bank"
    },
    "doc": "999999-RNF",
    "dueDate": "2018-10-11",
    "cnpjCLI": "999999999999",
    "cnpjREP": "999999999999"
  }]
}
```

Preciso imprimir os itens separadamente no HTML.
Para separar, estou tentando algo como o código abaixo, porém quando imprimo com `<div id='demo'></div>`, a resposta é `undefined, undefined`.

```
   var txt = this.responseText;
   var obj = JSON.parse(txt);
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = obj.value + ", " + obj.uri +" ... <br>";
```

Comment: Você viu que seu JSON possui um atributo `items` que é um array? Tentou usar `obj.items[0].Value`? `value` é diferente de `Value`. Outra coisa, `uri` está dentro de `boleto`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olá!

A resposta da sua requisição é um objeto com o atributo `items`, sendo que este é um array.
Para você imprimir todos os itens, você necessitaria iterar sobre o mesmo, passando por cada item da lista e imprimindo-os na tela.

```
response.items.forEach(item => {
      const p = document.createElement('p');
      const texto = document.createTextNode(`${item.value}, ${item.boleto.uri}...`);
      p.append(texto);
      document.getElementById("demo").append(p);
})
```

*Abaixo um exemplo:*

```js
const response = {
  "items": [{
      "value": 2149.44,
      "boleto": {
        "uri": "link.pdf",
        "digits": "0000000000000000000000000000000000000",
        "bank": "Boston Bank"
      },
      "doc": "999999-RNF",
      "dueDate": "2018-10-11",
      "cnpjCLI": "999999999999",
      "cnpjREP": "999999999999"
    },
    {
      "value": 2149.44,
      "boleto": {
        "uri": "link.pdf",
        "digits": "0000000000000000000000000000000000000",
        "bank": "Boston Bank"
      },
      "doc": "999999-RNF",
      "dueDate": "2018-10-11",
      "cnpjCLI": "999999999999",
      "cnpjREP": "999999999999"
    },
    {
      "value": 2149.44,
      "boleto": {
        "uri": "link.pdf",
        "digits": "0000000000000000000000000000000000000",
        "bank": "Boston Bank"
      },
      "doc": "999999-RNF",
      "dueDate": "2018-10-11",
      "cnpjCLI": "999999999999",
      "cnpjREP": "999999999999"
    },
    {
      "value": 2149.44,
      "boleto": {
        "uri": "link.pdf",
        "digits": "0000000000000000000000000000000000000",
        "bank": "Boston Bank"
      },
      "doc": "999999-RNF",
      "dueDate": "2018-10-11",
      "cnpjCLI": "999999999999",
      "cnpjREP": "999999999999"
    },
    {
      "value": 2149.44,
      "boleto": {
        "uri": "link.pdf",
        "digits": "0000000000000000000000000000000000000",
        "bank": "Boston Bank"
      },
      "doc": "999999-RNF",
      "dueDate": "2018-10-11",
      "cnpjCLI": "999999999999",
      "cnpjREP": "999999999999"
    },
    {
      "value": 2149.44,
      "boleto": {
        "uri": "link.pdf",
        "digits": "0000000000000000000000000000000000000",
        "bank": "Boston Bank"
      },
      "doc": "999999-RNF",
      "dueDate": "2018-10-11",
      "cnpjCLI": "999999999999",
      "cnpjREP": "999999999999"
    }
  ]
};

response.items.forEach(item => {
  const p = document.createElement('p');
  const texto = document.createTextNode(`${item.value}, ${item.boleto.uri}...`);
  p.append(texto);
  document.getElementById("demo").append(p);
})
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Olá...

Parece que o erro está aqui:

```js
ocument.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = obj.value + ", " + obj.uri" ... <br>"
```

Note que você parseou o **obj** que tem uma propriedade 'items'.

O correto seria:

```js
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = obj.items[0].value + ", " + obj.items[0].boleto.uri" ... <br>"
```